# How to find and count the patterns of indentation within some specific comments in Java

Tags: java, indentation, code-metrics

Let's say, within a single file, I have the following java code:

```
  //#if defined(LOGGING)
4    static {
8        if (System.getProperty(ARGO_CONSOLE_SUPPRESS) != null) {
12            Category.getRoot().getLoggerRepository().setThreshold(Level.OFF);
8        }
4    }
  //#endif
```

Or, this:

```
//#if defined(LOGGING)
0 static {
0 if (System.getProperty(ARGO_CONSOLE_SUPPRESS) != null) {
0 Category.getRoot().getLoggerRepository().setThreshold(Level.OFF);
0 }
0 }
//#endif
```

The two comments are added in the file, in addition to the code, and the numbers show the number of spaces (they are added only here for ilustration). Now, my purpose is to identify the two patterns of indentations between the comments: Bubble (first piece of code) or Straight (second piece of code) one.

Ideally, I'm trying to say, for example:

`LOGGING: Bubble 1, Straight 1`

`LOGGING2: Bubble 15, Straight 14`

... (and so on, for each `//#if defined(...) ... //#endif`.

To find the indentations I'm using the following method:

```
    public static void lineIndents(File file) throws IOException {
        scan = new Scanner(file);   
        while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String strLine = scan.nextLine();

        if(strLine.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(strLine); 
        } else {
            if(strLine.charAt(0) == '\t') { 
                System.out.println("t" + strLine.lastIndexOf('\t') + strLine);
            } else {
                //writeIndents(file, strLine.indexOf(strLine.trim()));
                System.out.println(strLine.indexOf(strLine.trim()) + ": " + strLine);
                }
             }
        }   

    }
```

Thank you for any suggestion, help, or comment!

Comment: Can you provide the expected output?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Also provide your attempts to find the ranges. Currently you are not looking for `#if` and `#endif` in your code. You are also not printing "Bubble" or "Straight" anywhere in your code.